# Stop Form Values From Inserting Into MySQL Database Twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I have `form` that inserts input data and file-locations into a MySQL database after submit. The script saves the data and the files successfully except it saves everything twice. I know it has something to do with having a `foreach` statement within a `for` statement, but I don't know how to re-arrange or re-write my code to have it accomplish what I want to.

I want it to do what it's doing right now, inserting the data into the database, but I want it to insert each value once.

```
<label>Length</label><input type="text" name="length[]" value="<?php echo   $sav['length']; ?>" size="2">
            <label>Width</label><input type="text" name="width[]" value="<?php echo $sav['width']; ?>" size="2">
            <label>Color</label><input type="text" name="color[]" value="<?php echo $sav['color']; ?>" size="4">
            <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $sav['quantity']; ?>" size="2">
            <label>Invoice Is Hidden</label><input type="hidden" name="invoice[]" value="<?php echo $invoice_no; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $sav['price']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="PaymentStatus[]" value="PAID">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE[]" value="2000000" />
            <input type="file" name="newImage[]">
```

**PHP Script**

*I am aware that `mysql_*` are depreciated functions and should be replaced with `MySQLi` or `PDO` methods*

```
<?php
require("addrow_info.php");

for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['length']);$i++) {
$newOrder = array(
    'length' => $_POST['length'][$i],
    'width' => $_POST['width'][$i],
    'color' => $_POST['color'][$i],
    'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'][$i],
    'price' => $_POST['price'][$i],
    'invoice' => $_POST['invoice'][$i],
    'paymentStatus' => $_POST['PaymentStatus'][$i],
    );

    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    foreach ($_FILES['newImage']['error'] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['newImage']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $imageName = $_FILES['newImage']['name'][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "decalImages/newOrders/$imageName");

            $uploadDir = 'decalImages/newOrders/';

            // Insert new row with user data
            $query = "INSERT INTO orders (PaymentStatus, invoice_no, length, width, color,  quantity, price, imagePath, orderStatus ) VALUES ('".$newOrder['paymentStatus']."','".$newOrder['invoice']."','".$newOrder['length']."', '".$newOrder['width']."', '".$newOrder['color']."', '".$newOrder['quantity']."', '".$newOrder['price']."', '".$uploadDir."".$imageName."', 'PENDING')";

            $result = mysql_query($query);

            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                echo "$query";
                mysql_close();
            }
        }
    }
}


?>
```

**How can I fix my code so that it only inserts the values into the database once?**

Comment: Where did you get the $_POST['length'] value?

Comment: Look in your web server access log -  is the script being _called twice_? That commonly happens if there's something like a rewrite from http to https, or an `<img>` with an empty `src=` attribute, causing the same URI to be used in the `<img>` tag, or a similar problem with a CSS `url()`. All difficult to spot, but common issues.

Comment: *"except it saves everything twice"* --- It may be because your query is inside the `foreach` loop. Try taking it out of it and see if that fixes 'er up. You've got a lot of stuff in that loop also.

Comment: It's not being called twice because I removed the part of the code that saves the $_FILES to the directory and it saves all of the values once. @Rottingham the value comes from the `form`.

Comment: I feel like it's one of your loops right there. Dump the loops and unit test with a single record, then slowly add back your loops and or data in either order, or both if one still fails to reveal the issue. Trust me, it's your view(form), your data model, or your controller... I doubt its the database at all.

Comment: I know for certain it's the inner loop, the one that saves the $_FILES, but if I remove that I still need a way to save the $_FILES and write the file locations to the database.

Comment: Well just pull the query insert out of the loop and let the files still save.

Comment: Also you have your open and close connection in sibling loops. You may want to combine that into a single loop or nested loops to solve this guy

Comment: But if I do that the file location won't save. Not only am I saving the file `$imageName`, but I am also saving the `name` and location of that file to the database, hence the query being in the foreach loop. Should I open and close the connection within the foreach loop?

Comment: no, you should open it before either, and close it after both. Optimally you compress that down to a single query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44368/discussion-between-relic-and-josan-iracheta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple comments have the right idea. You're looping through the number of files which can be up to the same length as the number of records, so you're entering in the query for a single record for every file up tot he number of records so you could at a max end up always putting in x^2 number of records.

Try dumping that inside loop, and using the original counter as the place mark since it's only one file per record... Your next challenge is going to be making sure that the if a record in the middle doesn't have a file but ones after it do, that that file gets attached to the correct record. This is to whet your pallet though:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['newImage']['tmp_name'][$i];
$imageName = $_FILES['newImage']['name'][$i];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "decalImages/newOrders/$imageName");

$uploadDir = 'decalImages/newOrders/';

// Insert new row with user data
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (PaymentStatus, invoice_no, length, width, color, quantity, price, imagePath, orderStatus ) VALUES ('".$newOrder['paymentStatus']."','".$newOrder['invoice']."','".$newOrder['length']."', '".$newOrder['width']."', '".$newOrder['color']."', '".$newOrder['quantity']."', '".$newOrder['price']."', '".$uploadDir."".$imageName."', 'PENDING')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
echo "$query";
mysql_close();
}
```